# Use Dynamic Javascript in iOS Share Extension

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, ios8-share-extension

I am developing a share extension for iOS 8 and it seem like i can run javascript code on page to grab some information like markup of the mage

But on the apple document it says that javascript code must be inside a .js file but my javascript code is coming from server and it is dynamic.

Is it possible to run javascript i downloaded from server or can I change js file contents everytime I need to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using the built-in support in the current share extension system.

The Javascript file needs to be listed by name in the extension's `Info.plist`, in the value of the `NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile` key. The file named there needs to exist in the app extension's bundle. But bundles are not writeable, so you can't replace or change the file.

You **might** be able to do something like you describe if you:

1. Include a basic JS file that just returns the entire page source to your extension.
2. Use `JavaScriptCore.framework` to further process that data in your extension.

I don't know of any reason why that wouldn't work, but I haven't tried it, and it's kind of unusual. Still, given your needs, it's worth investigating.